# JSP - Date formatting and Google cache

Tags: java, jsp, caching

I want to display a formatted date on my JSP page, so I use:

```
<fmt:formatDate pattern="MMM d" value="${myEvent.date}"/>
```

It works perfectly. It is displayed on the page as

```
Nov 28
```

However, a strange thing happens when it is cached by Google - the date on the cached page is displayed like this:

```
2016-11-28 20:00:00.0
```

Can anyone explain this? Shouldn't the formatting happen on the server? Doesn't my application server (Tomcat) send only the HTML to the page? How does Google know that this was in fact a Java date in the first place?

Just to clarify, to get to the cached version of the page, I perform a search on Google that displays my page in the results and I click on the down arrow and get to the cached version of my page.

Comment: You're correct: Google should have access to only the HTML markup that's ouput by the JSP/Servlet - there's no other way. So it begs the question: where did the Google cache get its value from? You should look in the source, and see what the markup really is like in the cached page, compare to the live version. Also don't rule out the obvious possiblities: the cached version of the page might have be created before you implemented the formatting, *or* this is simply a bug in Google's caching code (Google is still staffed by humans and they do make mistakes).

Comment: Compare Google's cached version with the one at http://waybackmachine.org also

Comment: I'm afraid you will hardly get real answers only random guesses unless someone working for Google and being aware of their internal algo ready to take the risk to loose his job just to answer your question may help. My random guess would be to say that a bot in charge of archiving your page is smart enough to recognize incomplete dates and replaces it with a complete date in order to keep the page information consistent whenever we read it. Indeed let's say that you access to your cached page in 2 years, reading Nov 28 would be a false info while 2016-11-28 20:00:00.0 would be correct.

Comment: For example the Data Highlighter understands dates so why not the bots in charge of archiving pages https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/2856609?hl=en

Comment: @NicolasFilotto thank you for your insight, it is helpful. What is infinitely strange is that, when I generated the same exact text (e.g "Nov 8" in my original example) by hard coding it or using other server side code, it did not change in the cache. It's only the JSP formatDate code causing it. Believe me I am not imagining things.

Comment: @kolossus please see my response to Nicolas. I really think I have stumbled upon something very interesting here. VERY strange.

Comment: show more of your HTML and jsp code in order to know in which tags you put your date exactly. Provide the code thats shows the date properly and the one that doesn't

Comment: @NicolasFilotto The first code snippet I have is the JSP code - that's the one that gets converted to the raw Java date. The code that doesn't get converted is just plain text "Nov 28". The two should output exactly the same thing, but the second is displayed as "2016-11-28 20:00:00.0" on the cached page. It's interesting that when I do "Fetch as Google" in webmaster tools, it shows it correctly. Only when cached.

Comment: No it is not what I expected, I expected to see the fragment of HTML/jsp code in which you have `<fmt:formatDate pattern="MMM d" value="${myEvent.date}"/>`

Comment: @NicolasFilotto assume that it's the only thing on the page in the body tag. If I use the formatDate tag, it gets cached as "2016-11-28 20:00:00.0". If I hardcode "Nov 28", it gets cached as "Nov 28". It's interesting to point out that the time (20:00) is the actual time from the original Java object in the formatDate tag, which is a mystery to me.

Comment: Maybe try to do a `diff` on the two versions of cached pages to make sure that no meta information is being passed along?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Apparently, when a JSP is requested without the "Accept-Language" HTTP header, the JSTL `formatDate` tag does not format the date and the result of `toString()` of the `Date` object is returned instead.

You can verify this by using [cUrl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CURL) to get the page source (instead of viewing the page source in Chrome).

**Bottom line**: If you you are using the JSTL `formatDate` tag and you want your dates to be formatted in Google's cache, you should explicitly set the locale. For example:

```
<fmt:setLocale value="en_US" />
```

I hope this helps someone.